# How do household radiator thermostatic valves work

Tags: radiator

I'm unclear how thermostatic valves work.
If set to 5 does that mean it continues letting in hot water into the 1. radiator regardless, or does it stop when it detects the 2. radiator is a certain temperature, or it is based on them 3. ambient air temperature.

And if 2/3 how does it detect temperature, what is max temperature ?

Comment: Not sure on the setting you are talking about most thermostats in the water system are fixed for example 180 degrees it opens and allows cool water into the motor. The electronic thermostats that power fans on models that have electric fans are also fixed the turn on at a specific temp then turn off when the temp has been reduced a specific amount sometimes 10 degrees but each make and model can be different.

Comment: Are we discussing hot water household radiators or water-cooled automobile radiators?

Comment: Hot water household radiators

Comment: I was thinking on a motor since I just did one for my grandson. The valves (very few) I have worked on a water boiler are similar but were adjustable.

Comment: I know it seems crazy but those thermostatic valves actually do detect room ambient temperature adjust  If you set it to '5' and the room is cool, it will allow a lot of the water circulating through the system into that radiator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it seems crazy but those thermostatic valves actually do detect room ambient temperature and increase or reduce the flow of water through the radiator based on that temperature.  It does not care about the temperature of the water flowing through the lines.  If you set it to '5' and the room is cool, it will allow a lot of the water circulating through the system into that radiator.  As the room warms, the valve starts to restrict the amount of water into the radiator.  When the room hits a predetermined level, the valve will shut all the water off flowing to the radiator.

Comment: Thank you, are you sure they restrict flow rather than simply open/close depending on whether ambient temperature reached ?

Comment: No the valves are smarter than that.  They gradually open and close based on ambient room temperature. There is detailed discussion of their operation on You Tube.